# Detect thread state when using @Async and @Scheduled in Spring

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, spring-boot

I am trying to achieve the following requirement in Spring.

I have two `@Async` threads that are running, let's call them `t_A` and `t_B`.

`t_A` is set with the `@Scheduled` annotation and it needs to run every 30 minutes (currently set to 5 sec). `t_B` should run constantly unless `t_A` kicks in and started its job at this point `t_B` will sleep and re-sample `t_A` status in **x** amount of seconds, once `t_A` job done `t_B` will continue its job till `t_A` will kick in again.

Currently I am stuck at two major points:

1. I am not sure how to get access to the threadpoolexecutor to check the thread state
2. When using `@Scheduled` it doesn't seems that the thread ever finishes, it seems that it just sleeps for the fixed time set in the annotation.

Any ideas?

Comment: aren't `Lock`s an option for that?

Comment: @FranciscoSpaeth could you provide and example for using locks?

Comment: is there any pseudo-code you though of for this implementation?

Comment: @FranciscoSpaeth well not really I posted this to get some ideas or examples so I can get started

Comment: Does `t_A` should wait until `t_B` finishes a loop iteration?

Comment: @NicolasLabrot well on each new iteration of t_B it should check the status of t_A, if it is in running state it will wait otherwise the iteration will continue

Comment: But does `t_A` have to check the status of `t_B` ? (And wait until `t_B` finishes an iteration?)

Comment: @NicolasLabrot Yes, it should check whether t_B is in a middle of its iteration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your level of contention is low a simple [ReentrantLock](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html) should do the job.

First create a shared lock between `t_A` and `t_B`:

```
final ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();
```

Prior to be able to executing their tasks, `t_A` and `t_B` have to acquire the lock and the lock will enforce that only one task (t_A or t_B) will be able to execute at a given time:

**t_A:**

```
@Scheduled(...)
public void process() {
    // Acquire the lock, wait forever until the lock owner t_B release the lock
    lock.lock();
    try {
      //do the job
    } finally {
       lock.unlock();
    }
}
```

**t_B:**

```
while (true) {
  // try to acquire the lock, wait 500ms until the lock owner t_A release the lock
  boolean acquired = lock.tryLock(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
  if (acquired) {
    try {
      //do the job
    } finally {
      lock.unlock();
    }
  }else{
    // t_A is already running, output a log for example
  }
}
```

Note that because your contention is low (2 threads at max) this code can be simplified using `synchronized`. It depends really on what you are trying to achieve with the lock.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, you saved me lots of time